# Yii2 GridView добавить подсказки в ссылки для сортировки

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Есть код

```
GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'user_id',
                        'label' => 'Пользователь',
                        'value' => function ($data) {
                            $users = app\models\Account::findOne(['user_id' => $data->user_id]);
                            return $users->firstname . ' ' . $users->lastname;
                        },
                    ],
                ...
         ]);
```

результат - таблица с готовыми колонками сортировки.
Можно ли как-то добавить подсказку (hint или title) к ссылкам для сортировки (label)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё нашёл. Нужно добавить строчку `'headerOptions' => ['title'=>'MyTitle']`
вот так

```
[
 'headerOptions' => ['title'=>'MyTitle'],
 'attribute' => 'meet',
 'label' => 'Page Title'
],
```